# DolphinDB single-node deployment vs single-server cluster?

Tags: dolphindb

I've learned about the basic difference between the two types of deployment. Still I got these questions after reading the tutorial. Any insights are welcome!

1. Since a node in the single-node deployment can realize the functions of three nodes (control/data/agent) in the cluster, why use a single-server for cluster deployment of three nodes (as they are all on the same computer)? In addition to the high-availability function, what other benefits are there?
2. After configuring 3 nodes in a single-server cluster, the available memory of each node is 4G according to the DolphinDB manual. Would the total memory be 12G? It seems much higher than the memory capacity of a single-node deployment...

Answer (score 0):

1. The single-node mode shares the same functions as the cluster mode, and the difference is that the former does not support nodes extension and high availability, while the cluster node can easily be deployed to multiple nodes and supports high availability.

It is deployed on a single server, the single-node deployment reduces the network transmission between nodes, indicating better performance and simpler deployment.

The single-server cluster deployment is usually used in intensive computing scenarios. Distributing computing tasks to different nodes can effectively isolate memory resources and improve computing efficiency.

2. Yes, but so far, the single-server cluster in DolphinDB's community version can only have up to 2 data nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Taking scalability and high availability into consideration, it is more recommended to deploy on a cluster.

A standalone mode reduces the network transmission between nodes with optimal performance and simple deployment.

The single-server cluster is often used for intensive computing scenarios, where computing tasks are distributed to different nodes or processes, which can effectively isolate memory resource competition and improve computing efficiency.